# Trouble reading and manipulating CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am making a website which has to have interactive visualizations of data. So I am trying to make a visualization first and I am using Python with Bokeh. So we received some .csv files and they are pretty large.

I already tried some stuff to visualize it but, I won't get it right.

The .csv file looks like this, in short:

```
;A;B;C;DA;0;0;1;2;B;0;3;0;0;C;0;0;0;1;D;1;0;2;0
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('coauth.csv', sep=';')
df
```

Does someone know a way to get it into an array or how to manipulate it. Because when I try to read the file with the method above, I get a column as first column which is unnamed:0

Comment: this probably is because when storing the file someone missed to add `pd.to_csv(index=False)`. If its rows go 0,1,2,3 I believe you are save to drop it

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought as well, but I do not think I am allowed to change the csv file

Comment: I am not entirely sure what the problem is here? You want to get rid of this column, or you want to get the DataFrame no matter the column into a list. What should the list look like ? Can you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn the CSV Information into a python list to then manipulate it, you can use [Pandas tolist() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.tolist.html) to turn it into a Python list.

Since Python Arrays are not really Arrays but lists, you can use Numpys [Array Function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) to turn it into an actual Array. Whatever you need. Lists or Arrays, you can do both.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but how do I do that, I get an error

Comment: And what is the error you are getting?
And what code do you use to get that Error?

Comment: I can't seem to get it into a list, do I have to read the csv file first as df = pd.read_csv and from there make it into a list?

Comment: It says datafram has no attribute 'tolist'

Comment: You have to specify the Column. You can`t just tell Pandas to turn the entire CSV into a List. You have to do simple Indexing. 
df['indexname'].tolist()

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because the `pd.read_csv()` function takes the first line of the input as the columns names if you don't precise otherwise with the argument `header=None`.

However, as your file has got only one line, I suggest you use the classic file reader python function :

```py
with open('coauth.csv') as csv_file:
    line = csv_file.read()

array = line.split(";")
```

You can then split your string object into a python list with the split() method.